# Get the indices of a range elements by relative order of the values

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator

I've just asked

[What's the idiomatic way to get the sort order of data, without actually applying it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184689/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-get-the-sort-order-of-data-without-actually-applyin)

(or see the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1577475/1593077) it was found to be a dupe on). So, I want to implement properly what seems to be the only suggested option - generating an array of indices and sorting it by the original data's relative order. Here's my code (ignoring includes):

```
template<typename RAIterator, typename Comparator, typename Size = size_t>
inline std::vector<Size>
sorted_indices(RAIterator first, RAIterator last, Comparator comparator)
{
    std::vector<Size> result(last - first);
    std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), 0);
    auto adapted_comparator = [&first, comparator](Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return comparator(first[lhs], first[rhs]);
    };
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), adapted_comparator);
    return result;
}

template<typename RAIterator, typename Size = size_t>
inline std::vector<Size>
sorted_indices(RAIterator first, RAIterator last)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<RAIterator>::value_type;
    auto comparator = [](const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs) { return lhs < rhs; };
    return sorted_indices<RAIterator, decltype(comparator), Size>(first, last, comparator);
}

template<typename Container, typename Comparator, typename Size = typename Container::size_type>
inline std::vector<Size> sorted_indices(Container& container, Comparator comparator)
{
    return sorted_indices<typename Container::const_iterator, Size>(
        std::begin(container), std::end(container), comparator);
}

template<typename Container, typename Size = typename Container::size_type>
inline std::vector<Size> sorted_indices(Container& container)
{
    return sorted_indices<typename Container::const_iterator, Size>(
        std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}
```

Have I covered all my bases or is there something I might be missing? Also, how legitimate is it to return the vector of indices?

Answer (score 1):

Two thing I noticed I can do are:

- use `std::less<T>` as a default comparator class
- set a default value for the comparator parameter, using the default initializer of the comparator class

The combination of these two cuts code length by half without reducing legibility (!):

```
template<
    typename RAIterator, 
    typename Size = size_t, 
    typename Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RAIterator>::value_type>
>
inline std::vector<Size>
sorted_indices(RAIterator first, RAIterator last, Compare compare = Compare())
{
    std::vector<Size> result(last - first);
    std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), (Size) 0);
    auto lookup_and_compare = [&first, compare](Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return compare(first[lhs], first[rhs]);
    };
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), lookup_and_compare);
    return result;
}

template<
    typename Container,
    typename Size = typename Container::size_type,
    typename Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
>
inline std::vector<Size> sorted_indices(Container& container, Compare compare = Compare())
{
    return sorted_indices<typename Container::const_iterator, Size>(
        std::begin(container), std::end(container), compare);
}
```

The downside is that you must then depend on `<iterator>` and `<functional>`; since I use them already for other things, I don't really mind.